# Process With No Name: A Possible Linux Rootkit?

Tags: linux, process, rootkit

## Situation

When I was looking at `gnome-system-monitor` one time, I saw a process without a name. Didn't bother me at first. Later, my laptop seemed to be heating up, and would see spikes in CPU activity - up to 100% on a single core, but when I look up sysmon/`htop` process listing, no process is consuming more than 2% or 4% of the total CPU (all processes listed, listing according to cpu activity.)

## What has been done

I looked up several things in the web. I did `rkhunter` and `chkrootkit`. No rootkits were found.

## Further observations

When I'm running `rkhunter` more of these nameless processes pop up, up to four at a time.

On sysmon, when I right click on the nameless process and then Properties: `gnome-system-monitor` crashes. On the short-lived window, there seems to be no useful information except than None or N/A.

## Question

1) Is this possibly a rootkit? 2) What can be done about it?

## Screenshot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwkxy.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, an answer. No, it's not a rootkit. It's a **bug in `gnome-system-monitor`**.

The bug is filed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+bug/606710

If this affects you, please help out in further elucidating this bug.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a root kit or just some innocent process which change it's owned title. You can find out which binary belongs to the process. In the output of `gnome-system-monitor` you can see the PID of the process. If you do an `ls -l /proc/$pid_you_found/exe` it will tell you which binary belongs to the process:

```
mtak@frisbee:/proc/7505$ ls -l /proc/7505/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mtak mtak 0 apr 14 16:15 /proc/7505/exe -> /bin/bash
```

Here you can see the binary associated with PID 7705 is /bin/bash.

Comment: Thanks, but these processes are ephemeral. I did what you said and the output as expected is: ls: cannot access /proc/29153/exe: No such file or directory

Comment: What use does the computer have? Server or terminal?
I remember seeing posts about nameless processes that had to do with "play on linux" and "wine"

Comment: @Bruno9779 I'm using it as a desktop computer. (Please see screenshot above.) I don't have PlayOnLinux installed and I'm quite sure no wine application was running when I made the tests above.